# blank document gives parse error: sintax error

Tags: php, wamp, require-once

I made a php named ControllerU.php file to study and it gives me a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\practica\model\User.php on line 14
the file only has

```
<?php 
    require_once "../model/User.php";
?>
```

Comment: You're not looking at the right file then.

Comment: i opened it directly from the directory, and opened all the possible files they all give me the same error, i quadruple checked

Comment: Can you edit your question and post lines 10-15 of the User.php file?

Comment: private $Pasword;
  private $Status;
  private $Rol;
 
 function __construct(argument)

Comment: post the whole of User.php, in the question, not comments.

Comment: its too long, how do i post it all?

Comment: `argument` is not right, did you mean `$argument`

Comment: actually no, i have no idea why i didn't saw that before, thanks, the method is not supposed to receive anything, thanks!